# iOS Sharekit Directely Uploading Video Files To Sharers

Tags: ios, video, upload, sharing, sharekit

I am currently attempting to use ShareKit to natively upload videos from the camera roll to most of Sharekit's sharers. I have fully installed Sharekit, however, since I am fairly new to Objective-C I am unable to fully understand how I might achieve my desired goal.

I have so far set up a target where I am able to record, edit and save videos to the camera roll, while providing live filters provided in the GPUImage framework developed by Brad Larson.

I have been able to share videos to Facebook using it's Graph API, But I was turned off using it because I did not know how to customise these videos, or how to natively upload from the camera roll, which is my desired uploading point.

Does anybody know how I might be able to upload video content and share it to these sharers? I have checked several issues and pull requests on the Sharekit Github page, [1,2] but nobody really went into depth as how to natively share videos.

Any help what so ever is always appreciated, and any code samples would be absolutely fantastic.

Regards,

Christopher

[1] (https://github.com/ShareKit/ShareKit/pull/661)

[2] (https://github.com/ShareKit/ShareKit/pull/212)